# How can I copy a jpg to my local over an ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal

Essentially, I am taking part in a program that requires tasks to be completed. I have done the majority of the task and identified a file (jpg) that I must view in order to get a flag.

I am having difficulties in viewing this jpg, as this machine (a vm (Manjaro) provided by the program) does not allow me to run apt-get, and it does not have sshfs or other commands required for other solutions I have found online.
A password is required to ssh to the server, and sshpass is not installed, so I cannot just copy it over in one line.

Edit: I also cannot use a key for scp instead of a password, as due to the program's restrictions I do not have permission to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really given a reason for using ssh. You're just trying to transfer a file, so perhaps just use something like nc? (a.k.a. netcat)

Comment: Sorry about that, should have specified that this task specifically requires the use of ssh. The task wasn't just to transfer a file, that was just the only relevant part (the part required to get the flag and finish).

Comment: In that case, scp or sftp are the standard ways to transfer files via ssh. Though from a cilent you could just do ssh 'cat /path/to/yourjpg' > yourjpg

Comment: The ssh 'cat /path/to/yourjpg' > yourjpg worked just fine, can't believe I didn't figure it out